# KeyError in do_POST procedure, but key exists

Tags: python, http

Here's the form my web server is serving upon a GET request (plus the contents of the memory list). I'm trying to make it so that when the message is submitted, it is appended to memory. Form is as follows:

```
form = ''' <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Server</title></head><body>
           <form action="/basic-server.py" method="post">
           <label>Message <input name="message" type="text" /></label>
           </form>
           </body></html> '''

memory = []
```

Now here is the content of my POST method using BasicHTTPRequestHandler:

```
def do_POST(self):

    length = int(self.headers.get('Content-Length'))
    postvars = parse.parse_qs(self.rfile.read(length))
    memory.append(postvars["message"])

    self.send_response(303)
    self.send_header('Location', '/')
    self.end_headers()
```

It throws a KeyError for 'message'. The thing that confuses me about this is that if I remove that line and print out postvars, it looks like a dictionary with a "message" key containing the message I type in on the form.

If I use `memory.append(postvars)` and input 'test' the application works and appends the following dictionary: `{b'message': [b'test']}`. What's with the 'b' characters? If I use `[b'message']` as a key, it works, but returns `[b'test']` to memory instead of simply test.

Comment: Can you add the output of `print(postvars)` when placed directly before or at the point where `memory.append(postvars["message"])` is to the post?

Comment: @3D1T0R If I use `memory.append(postvars)` and input 'test' the application works and appends the following dictionary: `{b'message': [b'test']}`. What's with the 'b' characters? If I use `[b'message']` as a key, it works, but returns `[b'test']` to memory instead of simply `test`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That information should be [edit]ed into the post. Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner, but it looks like Matt Cook's got you covered in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341464/keyerror-in-do-post-procedure-but-key-exists#45355547)

Comment: @3D1T0R Yep, I figured it out eventually. Your response actually helped me to test and debug it, so thank you! I'll put that stuff in the main post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Fix

You need to decode the information pushed through the post request.

#### Before

```
postvars = parse.parse_qs(self.rfile.read(length))
```

should become...

#### After

```
postvars = parse.parse_qs(self.rfile.read(length).decode())
```

## Explanation

In the original code, postvars is a dictionary of byte literals instead of string literals. [Here is a good explanation of this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

So in **before**, `postvars` == `[{b'message': [b'Post Message']}]`, meaning the key and value are both byte literals. You can't use the string `['message']` as a key because the key is a byte instance, not a string instance. The key here is `[b'message']`.

In **after**,  `postvars` becomes `[{'message': ['Test']}]` - the key and value are now decoded into string instances as expected.